# Smack someone from behind with your crotch

Tags: word-request

What is this called in English I describe the situation as follows:

When a boy goes behind a girl, front-to-back position, especially when the girl is distracted because it makes it funnier to him, hits (kind of smack) her butt using his crotch including the part where his genitals are and then runs away.

Occassionally boys who are close friends do that, too, just to tease eachother. Sometimes that strong that the other one bends backwards somehow or is pushed forward.

Actually it's a kind of sexual harrassment thing if the girl/boy is not OK with that.

The word that I'm looking for doesn't need to include *running away*, or *being funny* although if it does that'd be even better. I was thinking of *bang someone* but I think that's too strong. They're not having sex or anything! Maybe this happens in a disco, too, and the girl either slaps the boy or becomes a date.

Comment: I meant 'crotch' thanks for pointimg it out. Actually it's not Japanese! It's Persian, my persian classmate asked me that and I didn't know it, so I posted it here. I'm gonna edit that BTW.

Comment: Well, Yuri is used by people from different countries, Korea, Russia, etc. Anyway, that's fine no worries.

Comment: Based on your description alone I think this will be difficult to answer. We don't know age, intent, reaction of the parties, location and maybe other things to understand the scene properly.

Comment: The particular meaning you're looking for is sufficiently subtle that the question might get better answers on english.SE than here on ell.SE. I think it's a difficult question even for native speakers.

Comment: I'd still go with "sexual harrassment" or "groping". They're not as specific, but I don't know of any English-speaking cultures where that's okay. Just a word of warning, there.

Comment: May I coin the noun "humpling"?

Comment: May I just warn you that attempting this is quite likely to end with a broken nose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for is "humping", which is often used to describe simulated sexual activity in the way you describe. It can also be used to describe actual sexual intercourse depending on the context and usage.

It certainly is behaviour that is demeaning to a woman or a person who it is done to. There's an infamous video hoax that apppears to show former Italian Prime Minister Silvio Berlusconi doing this behind a woman on the street as he enters a building.

The other sense in which humping is used is when a dog decides to "hump" your leg. It may be trying to have intercourse with your leg, but you would probably want to say:

> "Stop humping my leg"

And then gently shove him off your leg!

Comment: Your answer gave me a clue, and I found the word **dry hump**. However, it implies a repeated action as a dog does as you said. Can I say, _"the boy gave her **a** sudden dry hump and then ran off"_ to imply that he did it suddenly and just a push. Does it sound natural to you?... that aside, if you want to **simply describe** the move, I mean what you see, what would you say? Something like _giving somebody a push by your crutch on their butt?_

Comment: No, because dry hump implies consent between people involved usually, and would be considered by some to be a form of sexual intercourse. Think about people getting very friendly in a night club while dancing.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then 'hump' is the best bet. And one more question I just edited my comment and added something. How to do simply describe the move?

Comment: Sorry I posted that prematurely (no pun intended). You would probably do better with a more mechanical description such as a "the boy thrusted his pelvis".

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear - I find this behaviour really detestable. It's an interesting question though, but you should be careful to not  to use this description and say the behaviour is good or people might think you are being cruel to women and sexually aggressive.

Comment: Yea, you're right. It's a kind of sexual harrassment as I said in my question. Someone brought it up and it made me think how I can say it in English. Sure I didn't mean no offence or anything like that.

Comment: Oh no offence taken at all. Just making sure you understand what using that kind of a description would potentially mean/imply

Comment: I don't think _humping_ is quite the right word for it, unless the person does this more than once or twice. I'm not sure if English has a term for this gesture that precisely fits the bill.

Comment: Perhaps not. But it does convey the sexually aggressive dimension of the act even if its meaning commonly indicates doing it more than once.

Comment: This answer is just wrong. "dry hump" or just "hump" indicate repeated action, not one off as described by the OP.

Comment: I disagree. As J.R says in the comment above, there likely is not a single term which describes this. Hump, humping or something similar describes the action in a way that many native speakers would understand - I think understanding meaning over a strict dictionary meaning is more important. Especially if the description was amended to say that the person was humped once, and then the other person ran away. It would be an adequate description of what the OP is asking for. Happy to do some edits if you like, or feel free to have a go yourself.

Comment: If we can't agree on this as the answer, I regret to say that the rather crude sounding mechanical description of "pelvic thrusting" is probably the only way to address this question.

Comment: Nik - You might want to edit your answer to change or remove the part that says, _"I think the word you are looking for is..."_ I agree with @user3169 – I **don't** think that's quite the right word for it, although I also wonder if that might be the closest we can get with a single word.

Comment: As a native speaker, I don't think "humping" is a good answer to this question. As others have said, it usually goes with repetitive action, not a single thrust, and there's usually some kind of attachment/grabbing associated with it. I could see it making sense if the perpetrator grabbed their victim's shoulders/abdomen/waist/etc. to do it, but not when there's only a pelvic thrust.

Comment: Happy to revise when I get a moment later today. I can't think of any word closer to describe the action itself and the situation where it is used. 

If you use it in a context where it is stated that there was a single hump, and that the perpetrator ran away immediately after, you have an accurate description that a native speaker who understands "humping" would understand clearly, without ambiguity. Acknowledging your points about it as a repeated action, I can update my answer to reflect that if people see that as a compromise.

Comment: For the record, it wasn't Silvio Berlusconi. Maybe you should edit that part.

Answer (score 8):

As both Nik and R have stated in the comments to Nik's answer, I feel the term you are looking for would be a ***pelvic thrust***.

This implies one movement whereby the pelvis is thrust from backwards to forwards in one motion. This can be done in the air (such as the dance move from the Time Warp) or against a person or thing. Doing this more than once would be called ***pelvic thrusting***.

Humping / Dry Humping on the other hand, is often used to express the act of simulated or real sexual movements (not dissimilar to thrusting the pelvis) or to the act of copulation itself. However, there is a heavier implication of there being an object that is being "humped" such as another person or thing.

Comment: "pelvic thrust" is technically the right term, but no teenager would say that.

Comment: @Ringo Nowhere does the question specify language that teenagers would use even though it may be casually implied. Further, any evidence for "no teenager would say that"? I know plenty that do.

Comment: well, yes, it was implied.

Comment: Implied and stated are not the same thing.

Comment: i said you had the right term, technically. what does that imply to you?

Comment: Thanks, it seems close. Can I say, _"the boy gave her a pelvic thrust"_ or _"the boy thrusted his pelvis against her butt?"_

Comment: I am not really sure about the context of the statement you are try to use however, "the boy thrust his pelvis against her butt", although not commonly used in colloquial conversation, will be understood.

Comment: Actually, there seems to be no single word or common thing to describe it. I've been thinking to describe the move, what I see, as if I'm describing it to a police officer as precisely as possible.

Comment: In that case, "the boy thrust his pelvis against her butt" would work as it describes exactly what is happening and leaves little room to be misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I think the term you're looking for is "bump 'n grind." http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=BUMP%20N%20GRIND

And it's also an R Kelly song.

Comment: Bump 'n grind seems to be quite similar to dry hump.

Comment: I think dry humping is something a man and woman might do on their couch alone. Or something a dog might do to your leg. Too much dry humping can cause "blue balls." It's really the act of sex, without penetration. Bump and grind would be more stylized (like a really over-the-top thrust) and has an exhibitionist aspect to it. Something you do in a public place (dance floor?), whether it's meant to be private or not.

Comment: Well, you can either "bump a girl from behind", or "grind on a girl from behind." Grinding is more sexually overt. A bump could be a fun little pelvic thrust, I guess.

Comment: I must say I would associate a bump 'n grind as more associated with dancing at a night club (also known as grinding), however neither humping or bumping seems to fit doing a thrusting motion only once as both seem like they are continuous movement.

Comment: However the bump and the grind are seen as part of the same act. Grinding would be understood just as you said. However bumping someone is not as clear. Bumping into someone has no sexual connotations at all. Bumping off someone is killing them. Bumping someone from behind to me would sound more like accidently running into them rather than thrusting behind them.

Answer (score 0):

At school we used to call it 'backshotting'. There you have it, it was done with a playful yet risque intent. I'm sure it was a term borrowed from some descriptions of sex in the 'doggie' position and as kids we used it because it sounded similar to a 'one hit' and run kind of escapade than constant humping. It was usually fo;;owed by running of with howls of laughter reverberating.

Usage: "Oh you should have been there at break time. Jonty backshotted Hayley and Claire in quick succession. Wham, bam.  It was a pisser!".